# Передача данных между окнами приложения

Tags: delphi, формы

Как сделать, чтобы после ввода данных координат (x,y) в первом окне во втором окне рисовался вектор по этим координатам? То есть, вопрос в том, как связать события первой формы со второй?

Comment: Координата (0, 0) в центре формы не может быть. Я бы сделал так: создал бы опорную точку в центре формы (X0:=Form1.ClientWidth, Y0:=Form1.ClientHeight), а текущее значение X и Y вычислял бы, опираясь на эти точки. Например: X:=X0+dx, где dx - значение x, которое ввёл пользователь; а Y:=Y0-dy, если dy отрицательное, то Y станет больще, т. е. ниже, и меньше будет при положительном dx. Если непонятно объяснил - E-Mail в профиле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать так, как это делается в случае с одной формой, но, обращаясь в коде к нужной форме. Для события обеих компонентов Edit OnChange первой формы задать перерисовку второй (если рисовать график на форме - Form2.Repaint), а в событии второй формы OnPaint взять координаты из первой так:

```
X:=StrToInt(Form1.EditX.Text);
Y:=StrToInt(Form1.EditY.Text);
```

а после этого рисовать на форме.
Необходимо обе формы друг к другу подключить командой **File -> Use Unit...**, а из списка выбрать для Form1 Unit2, и наоборот.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался) а еще такой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы координата (0,0) была в центре формы?

Comment: Лучше рисовать не на форме, а на `Image` (вроде так называется). Тогда изображение не будет "стираться" другими окнами.

Comment: На Image, конечно, лучше рисовать. Хотя, при рисовании на форме (или в PaintBox) в событии OnPaint всё рисование производить, то при стирании изображения другими окнами оно будет перерисоваываться.